# Reliably fetch LDAP (AD) updates

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, openldap, data-consistency

I need to sync users and groups from LDAP server. Currently only Active Directory is required.

I've looked at `whenChanged` attribute [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458484/9253292). But it will be tricky to detect delete operations, I guess.

Are there any protocols to do that, standard or AD specific?

---

Currently my "TODO" consists of: AD dirSync, AD Connect, [RFC4533 (LDAP Sync Operation)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4533#:%7E:text=This%20document%20defines%20the%20LDAP,that%20extend%20the%20Search%20Operation.), [RH syncRepl](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/10/html/administration_guide/content-synchronization). Additional pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For Microsoft Active Directory use of the [LDAP_SERVER_DIRSYNC_OID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/2213a7f2-0a36-483c-b2a4-8574d53aa1e3) control is the correct method.

You can Google for examples of its use.

Comment: [I've read](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/end-of-support-for-dirsync-and-azure-ad-sync-is-rapidly/ba-p/245242) that `dirsync` is deprecated. Is it deprecated only for sync with Azure AD and fine for custom needs?

Comment: I'm facing problems with DIRSYNC_OID (code 53, unwilling to perform), could you help?

Comment: There are tow permissions required depending on what you are trying to accomplish:
- Replicate Directory Changes
- Replicate Directory Changes All